# For XML Path error(XML parsing: line 1, character 29, well formed check: no '<' in attribute value")

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am getting the following error while using FOR XML PATH(''):

XML parsing: line 1, character 29, well formed check: no '<' in attribute value"

I have googled it but do not see any links. Please help.

Comment: The error says that you have invalid XML somewhere. Specifically you have an attribute value that contains the character `<` where it should have `&lt;`. This code will give you the exact same error. `declare @X xml = '<X A="<" />'`. I have no idea how you manage that using `for xml path` but if you post some code that reproduces the error perhaps someone can help you.

Comment: The problem was not with For xml. It was somewhere else and i was able to fix it. Sorry for bothering you and thanks for looking into it.